# Getting issue while runing Keras on GPU

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

I am successfully can run model on CPU.
But I can't use GPU due to issue listed below.
I think it's related to Conda but I have installed tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu via pip.
How to fix it?

```
  Using TensorFlow backend.
  Found 1864 images belonging to 15 classes.
  Found 792 images belonging to 15 classes.
  Epoch 1/20
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\NN_Music\fma_small\model_train.py", line 102, in <module>
    validation_steps=(nb_validation_samples / batch_size)
  File "E:\programs\Conda\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\programs\Conda\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 1121, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "E:\programs\Conda\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\programs\Conda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2042, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "E:\programs\Conda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1762, in train_on_batch
    outputs = self.train_function(ins)
  File "E:\programs\Conda\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2273, in __call__
    **self.session_kwargs)
  File "E:\programs\Conda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "E:\programs\Conda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1124, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "E:\programs\Conda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "E:\programs\Conda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
```

I have tried to check if GPU is present - yes.

```
name: "/cpu:0"device_type: "CPU",
name: "/gpu:0"device_type: "GPU"
```

Here is my source code:
[model_train.py](https://github.com/Vital95/NN_Music/blob/master/model_train.py)

Comment: Your error message is incomplete....

Comment: Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: Is that it? Isn't there an error message together with the traceback?

Comment: Yes - that's all....
https://ibb.co/nwoFrG

Comment: btw, I am using Visual Studio Code, But I don't think that it shrinks the errors.

Comment: Have you installed all the cuda drivers, Cuda Toolkit and CuDNN, and have checked they're working properly?

Comment: With this code, you do not need to use device scopes e.g. `with K.tf.device('/gpu:0')` to make sure it runs on a GPU. Only you need to have `tensorflow-gpu` installed and CUDA/CuDNN environment. If you want to use device scopes, then use Tensorflow `session.run()` instead of `fit_generator()`

Comment: Yes all according to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5968

Comment: how to test if tensorflow-gpu is working?